# Reorder factor levels in table1 in R

Tags: r, data-science

I am putting together a descriptive statistics table in R using the table1 project and noticed that regardless of how I order factor variables, the table1 function defaults to sorting these factor levels in alphabetical order. For example it sorts income categories in the order of "10k-20k, 20k-30k, etc..., Less than 20k" because L comes after numbers in alphabetical order. I would like for the "Less than 20k" variable to be the first row for income. There are other cases for this table where the variable is ordinal and thus alphabetical order may mess with the order that I'd like to see displayed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I tried reordering the factors in the tidyverse, but table1 seems to default to alphabetical sorting for factor levels

Comment: Please include in your question some example data and code which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Without more info I can't be specific but my guess is this could be solved by passing levels to `factor` when you are converting the income column to a factor. See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/factor for more details

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You use the `levels=` argument in `factor()`:

```
set.seed(42)
lbl <- c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "No Opinion", "Agree", "Strongly Agree")
dta <- sample(lbl, 25, replace=TRUE)
dta.f1 <- factor(dta)
table(dta.f1)
# dta.f1
#             Agree          Disagree        No Opinion    Strongly Agree Strongly Disagree 
#                 5                 6                 2                 5                 7 
dta.f2 <- factor(dta, levels=lbl)
table(dta.f2)
# dta.f2
# Strongly Disagree          Disagree        No Opinion             Agree    Strongly Agree 
#                 7                 6                 2                 5                 5
```